# How can I set default keyboard layout for new apps/windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have two keyboard layouts, English and Russian. When I open a new app or a new window within an app by default my keyboard layout is set to Russian until I change it. But I would like it to be set to English by default. Is there a way to configure it like that? Thanks.